# Desktop computer connected to Gigabit Ethernet does not speedtest to full Internet speed

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, internet-speed

My main home computer is a recent Win10 desktop with a Gigabyte B450M motherboard (Ryzen 3600, 32GB ram). The motherboard has a Gigabit Ethernet port connected to a regular Gigabit switch, then to a Linksys Velop Router/AP that is connected to my Internet provided cable modem. The cabling is all CAT5e. The Internet package is 400mbps down and 50mbps up.

I can run a speed test from the Velop router (via its web interface) and the results I'm getting are a consistent 450mbps DOWN/56mbps UP. And I get this results essentially every time I run the test.

Now, on my desktop, I use the Ookla speedtest application (not the web site) and I get a different result all the time. Results range from 220mbps to up to 388mbps. I've conducted daily tests for the last month and the reported average is 288mbps DOWN/56mbps UP.

Why would my desktop computer have issues reaching the full speed of my Internet connection? Anything I could test to find the cause? Thanks.

Comment: If you use other websites that test your speed what is your performance like?

Comment: Which server do you select in the Ookla Speedtest app? Does it have one offered by your ISP?

Comment: @Ramhound I tried using other sites but I often get even slower speeds. I find the Ookla app to be the solution that shows the speed the closest to the test from the actual Velop Router/AP.

Comment: @user1686 I tried different servers and the ones close to my home and operated by the big telcos provide the fastest speeds, but still not up to the 400mbps I would expect. My provider has a speedtest online but their server is 160 miles away from my home and I get slower speeds when compared to the Ookla app.

Comment: Do you happen to have a _second_ computer that you could connect to the same Ethernet, and use iperf3 to run a completely local test between the two? Have you tried connecting the desktop directly to the modem? (Some routers have things like parental filtering which are quite CPU-demanding compared to basic forwarding.)

Comment: Thanks @user1686 for the recommendation. I tried iperf3 with a second laptop connected closer to my Internet modem and I got some results. When my desktop was the client connected to the laptop, I got essentially 921 (normal) and 891 (reverse) Mb/s. This tells me that the speed on my internal network is capable of reaching close to Gigabit. However, when using my laptop as the client, I got 376 (normal) and 936 (reverse) Mb/s. Strangely, I could not go higher than 376 Mb/s when laptop was client but when desktop was client in reverse (data in same direction!?!) I reached much higher speed?

Comment: That's a bit odd, yes. Was the laptop connected to Wi-Fi or Ethernet or both simultaneously? (If both, sometimes outbound TCP connections end up taking a different path than inbound ones...) Was it connected to AC power and not overheating or otherwise overloaded? (Sending data at gigabit rates does need *some* CPU power.)